# TableAdapter Update fail

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, tableadapter

I have a VB windows Form project that connects to several DataTables in an Access DB. On my form I have several textboxes, comboboxes and datetimepickers that are bound to those sources. With one table in particular when I try to update the tableadapter after editing one of the textboxes the update method fails. No exceptions are thrown, but the update method returns a zero value and the data is not updated. The update **will** work when just the comboboxes or datetimepickers are edited, but as soon as a textbox is edited also, update will not work.

Other DataTables within the project are set up in the same manner but are not having update issues. I can't figure out what about this one particular table is causing an issue. Can anyone give me any thoughts on where or what to troubleshoot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try adding another textbox or other control pointed to the same source and see if you can get that one to update.  Could be something funky with the control's settings that you're missing, and if you start over, it would be fine.

Comment: Thanks, Beth. I added a new bound textbox but update still would not work. When I added a new DateTimePicker it worked fine. It seems to be something to do with textboxes in particular.

Comment: does this help? http://geek-goddess-bonnie.blogspot.com/2009/09/fun-with-datasets.html

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!! Rewrote the code in that link (I'm new to programming but believe it's in another language) and it worked like a charm. I'd been stumped for days. So much appreciated, Beth!

Comment: I think you're not the first one to have that problem.